# Code formatting for coffeescript/javascript

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow, syntax-highlighting

I keep seeing Coffescript questions that lack the javascript tag, so any posted code does not get any highlighting.

Would it be possible to get highlighting with just the Coffeescript tag without having to add (or edit in) the other?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes.

I've set the language for syntax highlighting [coffeescript](/questions/tagged/coffeescript) to the default (autodetect) so it should highlight just fine without any other language-specific tags now.